# How do we prove that $\textbf{P}(A) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c})$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have an equation that I want to prove, Pr()=Pr(∩)+Pr(∩¬).
I used the inclusion-exclusion principle to expand it to
A + B - (A ∪ B) + A + ¬B - (A ∪ ¬B) = A, then stated that the terms B and ¬B cancel eachother out through the definition of complement.
Then I argued that (A ∪ B) and (A ∪ ¬B) are disjoint, and therefore the probability that they both occur is zero, through the axiom of normalization.
I have left myself with A + A = A and I'm not sure if it is a problem that I have made earlier in the proof, or that I am not understanding the axioms.

Comment: Notice that

$$A = A\cap \Omega = A\cap(B\cup B^{c}) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{c})$$

Then apply the finite additivity property of the probability measure.

Comment: If $S1,S2$ are disjoint, $P(S_1\cup S_2) = P(S_1)+P(S_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Inclusion -Exclusion principle we have:

$P(S\cup R) = P(S)+ P(R) -P(S\cap R)$

Let $S = A\cap B$ and $R = A\cap B^c$

1_$S \cup R = (A\cap B )\cup (A\cap B^c)$
$\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,=A\cap (B \cup B^c) $
$\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,=A \cap \Omega$
$\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,=A$

2_$S\cap R = (A\cap B )\cap (A\cap B^c)$
$\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,=(A\cap A )\cap (B \cap B^c)$
$\quad\quad\quad\,\,=A\cap \varnothing$
$\quad\quad\quad\,=\varnothing$

So $P(S\cap R) = P(\varnothing) =0$

And so we are done.